# Where should I seek for help if I can't understand the math steps in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, computational-mathematics

A very common situation that I often run into when reading books and papers is that, the authors usually skip the underlying steps and jump straight to the final math expression, which has a rather different form compared with the original.

They say that the conclusion can be derived easily or obviously, but I am really unable to derive it. I can't even understand what each term in the result represents.

I tried searching on google, but nobody asked question concerning a specific step in a paper. I tried consulting my professor and the fellow classmates, but they admitted that they would never bother with a small question that doesn't affect the conclusion.

Where should I seek for help then? I don't even know which branch of math I need to look into. I was advised to ask question on math stackexchange, but it doesn't seem that there're enough people discussing here.

Comment: Different results draw from different fields. You'll need to provide more detail in your question if you want help.

Comment: Actually I'm not seeking for the solution to any specific question. I'm looking for a procedure to follow when encountering such problems.

Comment: Have you read books on calculus and linear algebra? Those are very essential for machine learning. Also, you can post the stuff you don't understand so others can help you.

Comment: The amount of mathematics that is used in machine learning is so vast that your question is unanswerably vague.